# Verify Complex Solutions of Riemann Zeta Function?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I've recently been trying to visualize the Riemann Zeta complex function by graphing it on a 3D plot.

I wrote some code to compute the value of the [following integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5#E12) of the Riemann Zeta function, which should be defined in *Re*(Input) $\neq$ 1:

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{2^{s-1}}{s-1} -2^{s} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(s\arctan(x))}{(1+x^{2})^{\frac{s}{2}}(e^{\pi x}+1)}dx$$

Where *s* is the complex Input.

Through the use of GNUPlot's code libraries, I graphed the following:

- *Re*(Input) - X-axis
- *Im*(Input) - Y-axis
- *Re*(Output) - Z-axis
- *Im*(Output) - Color

As far as I understand, this is one of the standard ways to visualize & graph complex functions.

With this setup I'm able to generate some plots:

[image]
[image]

Plots above depicts the function on -5 < *Re*(Input) < 5 and -5 < *Im*(Input) < 5. (forgive the messed up colorbar label on the right, it appears that C++'s GNUPlot library is quite old...)

[image]
[image]

Plots above depicts the function on -30 < *Re*(Input) < 30 and -30 < *Im*(Input) < 30.

So far, so good. However, I want to be able to verify whether my code produces the correct answers for this representation of the RZ function.

I'm able to compare some of my answers to some of the known answers out there, such as any answer with *Re*(Input) > 1, [real negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Negative_integers) and [discovered nontrivial zeroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Nontrivial_zeros), and those all appear to check out. However, apart from those, I haven't really been able to find a good way of reliably verifying the rest of my answers here. Most popular online function graphing calculators either fail to compute that integral function (such as [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)), are unable to accept complex inputs (such as [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing?lang=en)), or only have static plots of it (such as [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html)).

Since I'm not a mathematician, and since I'm not aware of all the possible resources out there or methods for verifying solutions for complex functions, I wanted to ask that here.

What would be some good ways of verifying solutions to complex functions, such as the Riemann Zeta function? Is there a tool that is used when computing complex functions such as these, for verifying solutions?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: +1 (also) to your posting.  Personally, I am not knowledgeable in this area.  However, your posted question is of such high quality organization, presentation, and provided background, relative to most of the questions posted at MathSE, that it is like a breath of fresh air.

Comment: You can use [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) "zeta(s): Riemann zeta function at s with s a complex or a p-adic number."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Wolfram Alpha (or Mathematica if you have access to that). Like this, for example:

[Plot3D[Re[Zeta[x+I y]],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot3D%5BRe%5BZeta%5Bx%2BI+y%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-5%2C5%7D%2C%7By%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D)

If you're a Python programmer, you can use the [mpmath library](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/zeta.html) to compute the zeta function for complex arguments.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of this page on Wolfram. Guess my original posting was incorrect, you can visualize the RZ function there.

I have a quick question, is it possible to also set a custom limit to the Z-axis on the displayed plots, like you did for the X-axis and Y-axis? I tried adding a `{z,-5,5}` to the argument, but it appears to not have an effect. Is there a way to add it? Also, is there a way to download the data points in some way?

Comment: In Mathematica you can do it with `Plot3D[Re[Zeta[x+I y]],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},PlotRange->{-5,5}]` (and there are also lots of other options you can give to customize the plot, plus you can rotate and zoom with the mouse), but that doesn't seem to work in WA. I also doubt that you can download the data points used for making a plot, but you can generate data yourself, for example `Table[N[Re[Zeta[2+I y]]],{y,0,2,0.1}]`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `mpmath` as suggested above, you should also try out `Sage` if you plan to do more computational stuff. There is even a online platform for you to try. [Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjMEKwjAQRO-B_MOAh2409iK9CL36H8FuMNBuZE2l9etNQHAu85gZ5oCJYxJGXOVeUhY8WNmamiLS5rG7qzWoUi6rCmjDCQnHWvQfLoFcL1kXctZY0_YY8Q5KXeOups85l8tEvzOP5ufBY2i8_zlqWHi8hfnF7gt9gCiZ&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) I give a template for a 3d interactive (!) plot for $f(x, y) = |\zeta(x + iy)|$. It looks quite funny:

[image]

If you need help with translating math formulas into Python/Sage code many can help here :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this library, I'll check it out! I tried plotting the function on an `-30,30` interval, and it appears to remain blank... not sure if it's not able to plot that, or whether I'm doing something wrong. I wrote my code in C++, and used the GNUPlot libraries to create the graphs in my posting. I actually tried this originally in Python, however the graphs were so detailed that it took AGES for Matplotlib to plot them. I guess I have to try the stuff you showed here.

Comment: @Runsva I haven't tried it myself but it's probably blank because of singularities and just exponential blow up, since the plot is linear scale by default. You can probably change it, or just throw some logs in yourself. Glad you learned something new :D

Comment: @Runsva: You're just seeing the pole at $z=1$. It will be a lot more interesting if you plot it on a larger domain.